# Cannot create max_apache event!

Tags: apache, sugarcrm

Has anyone seen this cryptic error or knows what it means?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by ZendMonitor.so and can be configured in zend.ini

```
; Maximum Apache processes to trigger event

zend_monitor.max_apache_processes=100

; Maximum Apache processes to trigger severe event

zend_monitor.max_apache_processes.severe=150
```

I don't know why the logs aren't timestamped and this isn't documented...